# nodeJS + express + jqtpl + app.engine

Tags: node.js, express

I've an issue in NodeJS, i'm new to this.
I'm using nodeJS, express and JQTPL to follow a tutorial about calling the github API but the problem is on the Application configuration, particularly on engine definition.

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    ...
    ;

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('view options', {layout: false});
    app.engine('.html', require('jqtpl').__express);
    });

// When we go to the URL "/" we go the the index.html
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/board", function(req, res) {
    res.render("board");
})
```

the app.engine call fail, here is the error :

```
 if ('function' != typeof fn) throw new Error('callback function required');

    ^
Error: callback function required
    at Function.app.engine (/var/lib/stickshift/51d5872b5973ca8338000033/app-root/data/547742/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:173:38)
    at Function. (/var/lib/stickshift/51d5872b5973ca8338000033/app-root/data/547742/app.js:15:9)
    at Function.app.configure (/var/lib/stickshift/51d5872b5973ca8338000033/app-root/data/547742/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:392:61)
    at Object. (/var/lib/stickshift/51d5872b5973ca8338000033/app-root/data/547742/app.js:12:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I understand what's a callback.. etc.. but the only way to call app.engine i found is builded like this.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jqtpl` seems to be broken (at least the version in the NPM repo; the GH version might work better): it tries to determine the version of Express, but it uses a property (`express.version`) that doesn't exist anymore.

Here's a workaround:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.engine('html', require('jqtpl/lib/express').render);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("index"); // this renders "views/index.html"
});

app.listen(3013);
```

Comment: Ok thank you i used jade while waiting your answer. I'm gonna try this.

you wrote that res.render(index) render public/index.html, but I thought express was looking for pages in views/. Am I wrong ?

In fact now my app doesnt redirect to index.html, I've not searched for a solution now but maybe it's because i put my index.html in views/ ?

thank you again

Comment: ahah, you gave me another hope and get it back !

Thank you anyway !

Comment: @ogdabou you want a redirect from `/index.html` to `/`?

Comment: Nop, i want to redirect from / to /index.html

Comment: @ogdabou well that would be easy (`app.get('/, function(req, res) { res.redirect('/index.html') })`), but why would you want that?

Comment: In fact, I simply want to redirect to index.html when your reach the webstite (ogdabou.com for example) and I thought app.get("/"....) could help me.

I did an app with Struts2 in my school and It returned index.html without configuration.

Or maybe i misunderstood the app.render

Comment: @ogdabou `res.render()` will render a template. I think you want to use [`express.static`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-static.html) (on that page it's called `connect.static`, but that's the same).